# google robot only show HTML structure for mobile device not apply CSS. why?

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have created a wordpress website with responsive, but when we have done mobile friendly test in google, it has shown me "your/my site is not mobile friendly".

I have observed that the CSS is not render by google robot. I have also allow google robot to search CSS file in our site by using robot.text file.

I'm putting my robot.txt file code below:

---

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Disallow: #Any folders we should not be allowing search bots to crawl.
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/cache
Disallow: /category/*/*
Disallow: /staging/
Disallow: /.hcc.thumbs/
Disallow: /10finsbury/
Disallow: /_db_backups/
Disallow: /affemailprdxn/
Disallow: /ajax/
Disallow: /assets_old/
Disallow: /assets_unk/
Disallow: /build_unk/
Disallow: /cgi_unk/
Disallow: /ciheropractice/
Disallow: /dekadesign-galaxy/
Disallow: /dekadesign-seroquel/
Disallow: /demowp/
Disallow: /dpulp/
Disallow: /eddynamics/
Disallow: /eddynamics730/
Disallow: /empwpstaging/
Disallow: /facebook-api/
Disallow: /furiousminds/
Disallow: /galaxy-cms/
Disallow: /galaxy-image-testing/
Disallow: /galaxy-test/
Disallow: /handt/
Disallow: /icehouse/
Disallow: /inxpress/
Disallow: /lead-usa/
Disallow: /liebhauserhome-ps/
Disallow: /maintenance/
Disallow: /ngbyliebhauser/
Disallow: /ngrebuild/
Disallow: /PIEFiles/
Disallow: /themefiletrans/
Disallow: /thememedwards/
Disallow: /repository/
Disallow: /staging/
Disallow: /staging/prdxn/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /timeclock/
Disallow: /qcoal/
Disallow: /zhero-palma/
Disallow: /zherokappl-cms/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/theme-wp/ANZBAIJuly152013.php/ANZBAI
Disallow: /wp-login.php/
Disallow: /wp-register.php/
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*.inc$
Disallow: /p13n_*
Disallow: /*.dll
Disallow: /servicetechnologies/
Disallow: /servicetechnologies
Disallow: /servicetechnologies/*
Disallow: /work-projects
Disallow: /work-casestudy
Disallow: /testimonial
Disallow: /testimonial/
Disallow: /testimonial/*
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Allow: /*.css$

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: /
Allow: /*.css$

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /
Allow: /*.css$
```

---

the screen short given below:

[Screen short of mobile not friendly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VltQr.png)

Comment: Have you checked whether the CSS paths are actually available to the Googlebot? There is a robot.txt tester in Google Webmaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the CSS file blocks from the .htaccess file.

So I have removed those line from .htaccess file now it is working fine. The issue has resolved.

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as bots are concerned, CSS files are not a thing. When any bot(including) GoogleBot tries to index your site, it is pretty irrelevant what color your header is. This is why css files are **never**(even though you have specified it in your robots.txt) indexed. So don't worry about it, your search listings won't be affected at all.